# Regarding "torch" package - with anaconda environment using vscode as editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, conda

I am currently working on project,where I use pytorch as deep learning environment. I have serious problem, that .... "When I use anaconda jupyter notebook terminal to run my ***.py** files. Then, it run properly. But, when I use the same environment within vs-code via **python_interpretor**, I can not get result and give me error "**torch module can not found**".

Can anyone have solution?. Actually, I see the packages using "conda list" and it includes torchvision inside environment. I also tried to install torch in base environment But, it does not work.

Please give me some solution. Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: VSCode is probably getting the wrong Python environment. Look at the lower left corner in code.

Comment: What do you mean by _anaconda jupyter notebook terminal_ ? Have you checked the VSCode documentation on using virtual environments?